# Railsチュートリアル10章にてテスト実行も、エラー解消できず

Tags: ruby-on-rails

初学者で拙い質問ですが、ご助言いただければ幸いです

## 現状

以下Railsチュートリアル10章10.18にてテスト実行もエラーが解消できずにいます
https://railstutorial.jp/chapters/updating_and_deleting_users?version=6.0#cha-updating_showing_and_deleting_users

## やりたいこと

短期ではこのエラーを解消したい。
また長期では、エラーメッセージの読み方を知りたい（恒常的なエラー解決能力向上の為）

## 実際に出ているエラーメッセージ

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 10292
Started with run options --seed 17476

 FAIL["test_login_without_remembering", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00005589839cf8f8 @name="UsersLoginTest">, 2.1944358210002974]
 test_login_without_remembering#UsersLoginTest (2.19s)
        Expected "nwXSaOjBsGs3DcngTp9DNQ" to be empty.
        test/integration/users_login_test.rb:54:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'

 FAIL["test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00005589834f2678 @name="SessionsHelperTest">, 2.621771213998727]
 test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil#SessionsHelperTest (2.62s)
        --- expected
        +++ actual
        @@ -1 +1 @@
        -#<User id: 762146111, name: "Michael Example", email: "michael@example.com", created_at: "2022-09-05 12:32:41", updated_at: "2022-09-05 12:32:44", password_digest: [FILTERED], remember_digest: "$2a$04$rowvhtmUB1Dz/Hw8Q5/JJebWQX5xjelWBf/637jv7W7...">
        +nil
        test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:SessionsHelperTest>'

  25/25: [===============================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:02, Time: 00:00:02

Finished in 2.64487s
25 tests, 60 assertions, 2 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

## 既に試したこと

チュートリアル８章まで遡り、該当箇所の確認
この場合test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb
の変位を確認

Comment: 有料で購入者などにしかアクセスできないらしい紹介リンク先なので、こちらのサイトでは対象外なのでは？ まずはサービス提供している運営元へ質問すべきでしょうし、それが一番早くて確実な解決法だと思われます。 問題が発生している対象のソースコード全般や動作環境などの情報が質問記事で提示できる(教材であっても他サイトへ公開可能としている)ならば質問として成り立つでしょう。

Comment: これは失礼しました。ご助言いただきました通り質問してみます。